# Exec external EXE in C# WebService not working

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a WebService that a program should run any exe.
Made the implementation of the service, I made a test case and the process works.

But if I call the WebService, the exe is not initialized.
I can not ententer the reason it does not boot

```
Configuracoes.Configuracao.URL = "C:\WA.exe";
```

code:

```
protected override object DoConsulta(ArgumentoDaConsulta argumentos)
{
    try
    {
        var exec = Configuracoes.Configuracao.URL;
        Process.Start(exec);
        return exec;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very BAD idea. I would strongly not recommend allowing arbitrary processes to be started on your server. It's a huge security risk.

Comment: Is an exception thrown?

Comment: A web service that allows remote execution of any process would require its own security layer to be safe.  Why not just use PowerShell or something that already has all that built in, instead of making your own web service for something like this?

Comment: There is already a large amount of serum running, making the integration between two systems of different companies and it became necessary to call the EXE WS by another company, not to have to change everything, yet the solution was to use his own WS. This WS is an internal network and not outside.

Comment: Seeing the windows task manager, the EXE is in the process tree, but I can not see your screen running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to services.msc, right click on your service, and on tab LOGON check **allow service to interact with the desktop.**